# Выбор последнего по дате файла из каталога

Tags: python

Изучаю *Python*, пытаюсь написать скрипт, который из определенной папки берет файл, который создался поздней других. Как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 11):

Пусть задан какой-то путь:

```
path = r'C:\Python27'
```

Нужно получить список файлов по этому пути:

```
import os
files = os.listdir(path)
```

На этом этапе желательно проверить, что список файлов не пустой. Делаем просто `if files:`, а все что расписано ниже - идет внутри блока if.

Превратим просто список файлов в список файлов с путями:

```
files = [os.path.join(path, file) for file in files]
```

Функция os.path.join() "прикрепляет" путь к имени файла. В зависимости от системы данная функция вставляет между путем и файлом либо прямой слеш, либо обратный, либо вообще ничего, если слеш уже есть в конце пути.

Оставляем в списке только файлы:

```
files = [file for file in files if os.path.isfile(file)]
```

Время создания файла будем определять функцией `os.path.getctime()`. Нужно найти файл, у которого дата модификации максимальна. Для этого воспользуемся функцией `max` с дополнительным параметром `key`, позволяющим задать функцию, которая будет применяться к каждому объекту из списка, минимальное будет определяться по соответствующим возвращаемым значениям:

```
>>> max(files, key=os.path.getctime)
'C:\\Python27\\LICENSE.txt'
```

В других ответах вижу `sort` либо `sorted`. Почему не применить его? Все просто: зачем сортировать список (возможно, большой), когда нужно всего лишь один раз пройти по нему и найти максимальное.

Comment: `os.listdir` возвращает имена не только *файлов*, но также и *каталогов*. А в вопросе фигурирует именно *файл*.

Comment: @kff, изменил ответ.

Comment: на Windows, лучше `os.path.getctime` использовать, чтобы найти файл, который был *создан* самым последним, а не *изменён* самым последним. Если [использовать `os.scandir()`, то можно вообще с O(1) (константа) памятью найти файл за O(n) (линейное) время, используя `max()`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477013/23044)

Comment: @jfs, на практике редко требуется сравнивать дату именно создания файла (хотя, могут быть и такие случаи), поэтому задание понял не так как в нем написано)

Comment: @insolor: вопрос явно говорит: *"файл, который создался поздней других"*, а не файл, который был модифицировано поздней других.

Comment: @jfs, okay, изменил ответ.

Answer (score 7):

```
import os

path = '/path/to/you/dir' # Путь к вашей папке

# Получим список имен всего содержимого папки
# и превратим их в абсолютные пути
dir_list = [os.path.join(path, x) for x in os.listdir(path)]

if dir_list:
    # Создадим список из путей к файлам и дат их создания.
    date_list = [[x, os.path.getctime(x)] for x in dir_list]

    # Отсортируем список по дате создания в обратном порядке
    sort_date_list = sorted(date_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    # Выведем первый элемент списка. Он и будет самым последним по дате
    print sort_date_list[0][0]
```

Comment: `os.listdir` возвращает имена не только *файлов*, но также и *каталогов*. А в вопросе фигурирует именно *файл*.

Comment: Решил не делать лишних проверок чтоб не загромождать код.

Comment: на Unix, `getctime()` не возвращает время создания, возможно лучше `getmtime()` использовать (время последнего изменения), чтобы код одинаково между платформами работал. [Нет необходимости `sorted()` использовать, можно `max()` вместо в этом случае использовать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/476814/23044).

Answer (score 4):

> ..скрипт, который из определенной папки берет файл, который ***создался*** поздней других.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

folder = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else os.curdir
entry = max((e for e in os.scandir(folder) if e.is_file(follow_symlinks=False)),
            key=lambda e: getattr(e.stat(), 'st_birthtime', None) or e.stat().st_ctime)
print(entry.path)
```

Смысл `st_ctime` зависит от системы:

- на Windows — это время создания файла
- на POSIX — это время последнего изменения мета-данных у файла (что может отличаться от даты создания файла)

`st_birthtime` это время *создания* файла на некоторых системах таких как FreeBSD.

На Linux некоторые файловые системы такие как ext4 также сохраняют `crtime` (не путайте с `ctime`) -- поэтому, если обязательно нужна именно дата создания, то можно что-то вроде [`xstat` bash функции](http://moiseevigor.github.io/software/2015/01/30/get-file-creation-time-on-linux-with-ext4/) использовать (она реализована поверх `debugfs` и `stat` -- сама по себе `stat` команда не возвращает Birth time на моей системе).

Чтобы найти файл, который был ***изменён*** последним, нужно использовать `st_mtime` атрибут.

Если сохранить вышеприведённый Питон код в файл `last_created.py` и положить этот файл куда-нибудь в PYTHONPATH (`sys.path`), то чтобы узнать какой файл был создан последним в папке `"здесь путь к папке"`, можно выполнить команду:

```
C:\> py -m last_created "здесь путь к папке"
```

Если [`.py` в %PATHEXT% и `py.exe` настроен запускать файлы Питона (`assoc .py`, `ftype Python.File`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9037346/4279), то можно выполнить просто:

```
C:\> last_created "здесь путь к папке"
```

---

Если необходимо следить за вновь созданными файлами в папке в реальном времени, то чтобы избежать постоянного перебора всех файлов в папке, можно использовать [`watchdog` библиотеку](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog), которая позволяет эффективно следить за изменениями в файловой системе (выполнять действия в ответ на события) и поддерживает разные платформы. Чтобы установить:

```
С:\> py -m pip install watchdog
```

Чтобы выводить на экран любые изменения в заданном дереве директорий:

```
$ watchmedo log "здесь путь к папке"
```

---

Вот версия `last_created.py`, которая поддерживает старые версии Питона (Python 2/3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Find the last created file in a given directory."""
import os
import sys
import stat

folder = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else os.curdir
files = (os.path.join(folder, name) for name in os.listdir(folder))
entries = ((path, os.lstat(path)) for path in files)  # don't follow symlinks
path, _ = max((e for e in entries if stat.S_ISREG(e[1].st_mode)),  # find regular files
              key=lambda e: getattr(e[1], 'st_birthtime', None) or e[1].st_ctime)
print(path)
```

На Питоне 2 на Винде, чтобы не иметь проблем с Юникодными именами, следует использовать Unicode Win32 API: `GetCommandLineW()`, `CommandLineToArgvW()` (Python 3 делает это автоматически). См. [Read Unicode characters from command-line arguments in Python 2.x on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/846850/4279). С этим изменением код работает даже, если имена не могут быть представлены в кодировке, используемой в текущей локали ([PEP 383](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383/)) на всех платформах (Python 2/3, Windows/POSIX).

Поведение данного кода при возникновении ошибок (файл исчез или нет прав доступа к файлу) отличается от первого примера, где [`e.is_file()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry.is_file) игнорирует 
`FileNotFoundError`.

[`os.path.isfile()` функция](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile), используемая в других ответах, возвращает `False` при возникновении любых `OSError` ошибок (если хочется этого поведения, то можно явно обернуть `os.lstat()`, `e.is_file()` вызовы в try/except блоки).

Дополнительно, в отличии примеров  кода в этом ответе, `os.path.isfile()`, `os.path.getctime()` следуют по цепочке `symlinks`, если необходима информация по самой записи в каталоге, то можно `os.path.islink()` и `os.lstat()` вызывать.

Версия, использующая [`os.scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) может быть быстрее версии с `os.listdir()`. Также `os.scandir()` может работать для очень больших директорий не загружая все записи в память сразу как это делает `os.listdir()`.

Answer (score 2):

Время создания файла можно узнать функцией `os.stat(path, *, dir_fd=None, follow_symlinks=True)`. Потом простенький цикл

```
fn = ""
day = 0

for n in glob.iglob("*.*"):
    if os.path.isdir(n):
        continue
    cday = os.stat(n).st_ctime
    if day<cday:
        day = cday
        fn = day
```

В итоге `fn` - имя самого позднего файла.

Для справки

- `st_atime` - время самого последнего доступа в секундах,
- `st_mtime` - время самого последнего изменения в секундах,
- `st_ctime` - зависит от платформы: время последнего изменения метаданных на Unix, или время создания на Windows, выражается в секундах

Comment: `os.iglob` возвращает имена не только *файлов*, но также и *каталогов*. А в вопросе фигурирует именно *файл*.

Answer (score 2):

Один из методов решения данной задачи может выглядеть, например, так:

```
import glob
import os


def last_modified_file(folder):
    files = list(filter(os.path.isfile, glob.glob(folder + "/*")))
    if len(files) > 0:
        files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x), reverse=True)
        return files[0]
    else:
        return None


file_name = last_modified_file("C:/Windows/System32")
if file_name:
    print(file_name)
else:
    print("No files in this folder.")
```

Можно записать всё в одну строку, используя генераторы списков и функцию `max`:

```
max([file for file in glob.iglob(folder + "/*") if os.path.isfile(file)], key=os.path.getmtime, default=None)
```

Но у вышеперечисленных решений есть недостаток - большой расход памяти на хранение списка полученных файлов. Чтобы уменьшить расход памяти, можно использовать итераторы:

```
def last_modified_file2(folder):
    result = None
    date = None
    for name in glob.iglob(folder + "/*"):
        if os.path.isfile(name):
            if not result:
                result = name
                date = os.path.getmtime(name)
            else:
                date2 = os.path.getmtime(name)
                if date2 > date:
                    result = name
                    date = date2
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Если используется линукс то можно так:

```
import commands
newest_file = commands.getoutput("ls /path/to/your/dir -apt1 | grep -v / | head -n 1")
```

Не то, чтобы совсем питон, но максимально коротко.