# Работа с большим количеством файлов

Tags: python, python-2.x

У меня директория, в которой находятся еще около 5 директорий. Каждая из этих директорий содержит огромное множество файлов. Мне надо проверить дескриптор каждого файла, а затем предпринять необходимые действия, например, удаление файла.

Дело происходит на рабочем серевере и процессор очень сильно грузится, когда я делаю дубовым способом, вот так:

```
[self.handle_file(path) for path in glob.iglob(PATH + '/*/*')]
```

Как можно это сделать более оптимально ?

Comment: В общем случае (когда система занята именно IO вызовами—не похоже на случай в вопросе), например если может быть миллион файлов или файлы в сетевой папке расположены, то `os.scandir()` может помочь. Вот [примеры](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477013/23044) [использования](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461144/23044).

Answer (score 4):

Никогда не используйте списковое включение для выполнения каких-либо действий! Во-первых, это анти-паттерн, а во-вторых, это очень неэффективно. В вашем конкретном случае, Python создаёт в памяти список путей до всех файлов, которые вернул `.iglob()`, и будет его там держать до тех пор, пока не пройдётся по всем элементам.

Comment: т.е. вместо квадратных скобок, используйте круглые, тогда будет создан генератор, который будет возвращать значения только когда действительно нужны

Comment: А ещё лучше воспользоваться классическим циклом. Включения предназначены для порождения данных без побочных эффектов.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, не понял про антипаттерн. list comprehension - это антипаттерн в целом или то как я его использовал ?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, ага, а еще хорошо работается с os.walk :)

Comment: То, как вы его использовали.

Comment: Если файлов реально ОЧЕНЬ много, то даже os.walk затупит. Я сперва хотел ответ про него написать, а потом передумал

Comment: @andreymal: `os.walk()` ограничен своим интерфейсом для ОЧЕНЬ больших директорий (вынужден списки возвращать для всей директории сразу)—что на практике редко имеет значение. Для своих особых нужд, можно изменить API и реализацию, например, генерировать parent, entry (тип `os.DirEntry`) пары [вместо `top, dirs, nondirs`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f6964187fa350a43696b89986b1b4dc3046d7ad8/Lib/os.py#L277-L415) хотя в частных случаях [(как в ссылке, которую я выше привёл), код может быть ещё проще (поддерживая огромные директории)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461144/23044)