# Как узнать дату создания папки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу найти в `python` функцию для получения информации о времении создания директории.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Python Выбор последнего по дате файла из каталога](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476802/23044) (мой ответ там показывает как не только на Windows получить дату создания).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import os
import time

path = '.idea'
a = os.path.getatime(path)  # время последнего доступа
b = os.path.getmtime(path)  # время последнего изменения
c = os.path.getctime(path)  # время создания (Windows), время последнего изменения (Unix)
print([time.ctime(x) for x in [a, b, c]])
```

Comment: А этот вариант будет работать во всех ОС или  в какой то конкретной? Например ctime есть примечание "Return the system’s ctime which, on some systems (like Unix) is the time of the last metadata change, and, on others (like Windows), is the creation time for path. " [1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime)

Comment: Я подобные функции на `php` использовал, по моему на винде не совсем корректно работает.