# выдача списка файлов

Tags: python

подскажите код, который выдает список всех файлов в заданном диске/папке с расширениями, размером и датой изменения/сохранения
нужно для дальнейшего отслеживания изменений в директории.
   пока получилось так

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
path_f = []
file1 = open('1.txt', "w")
for d, dirs, files in os.walk(u'd:'):
    for f in files:
        path = os.path.join(d,f)
        path_f.append(path)
file1.write(str(path_f))
file1.close()
```

осталось разобраться как добавить к каждому файлу размер и дату сохранения/изменения

Comment: Гуглите в сторону стандартной библиотеки "os". В частности, вам могут пригодиться функции: os.walk - генератор списка каталогов и файлов внутри заданного каталога. os.path.getmtime - возвращает время последнего изменения файла os.path.getsize - возвращает размер файла

Comment: Похоже на [XY-задачу](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795/23044). Уточните вопрос. Какие изменения вы хотите отслеживать? Попробуйте [watchdog модуль](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog).

Comment: Вам нужны `walk` и `stat` из модуля `os`.

Comment: Вы случайно не [это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538673/) ищете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from os import path, listdir
from time import ctime

folder = 'libs'
for name in listdir(folder):
    full_name = path.join(folder, name)
    if path.isfile(full_name):
        name_, _ext = path.splitext(name)
        time_info = [ctime(fn(full_name)) for fn in (path.getatime, path.getmtime, path.getctime)]
        file = {
            'каталог': folder,
            'файл': full_name,
            'файл_имя': name_,
            'файл_расширение': _ext,
            'время последнего доступа': time_info[0],
            'время последнего изменения': time_info[1],
            'время создания': time_info[2],
        }
        print('\n'.join('{:<30} : {}'.format(*f) for f in sorted(file.items())), '\n')
```

out:

```
время последнего доступа       : Sun Jan 22 16:41:03 2017
время последнего изменения     : Sun Jan 22 16:41:03 2017
время создания                 : Sun Jan 22 16:41:03 2017
каталог                        : libs
файл                           : libs\log.py
файл_имя                       : log
файл_расширение                : .py 

время последнего доступа       : Sun Jan 22 23:08:33 2017
время последнего изменения     : Sun Jan 22 23:08:33 2017
время создания                 : Sun Jan 22 23:08:33 2017
каталог                        : libs
файл                           : libs\trace_dec.py
файл_имя                       : trace_dec
файл_расширение                : .py 
...
```

Comment: `os.scandir()` можно использовать как более читаемое и эффективное решение, чтобы получить список файлов с мета-данными. Вот [пара](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477013/23044) [примеров](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461144/23044)

Comment: @vadim vaduxa Только сейчас увидел что Ваш пример не собирает данные из подпапок

Answer (score -1):

Стандартный модуль glob должен помочь

```
from glob import glob

fileslist = glob("путь к диску/**/*")
```

** - значит все каталоги рекурсивно, * - все файлы

Время изменения и прочее можно запросить через `os.stat()`

Comment: `**` не имеет специального значения, если `recursive=True` не передать.

Comment: но работает без

Comment: попробуйте с вложенными директориями чтобы убедиться, что без явного флага рекурсивное поведение не работает.