# информация о файлах через os: проблема с выводом размера, даты создания

Tags: python-3.x, файлы

Дали задание написать программу, что выводит данные о файлах в указанной директории их имя дату создания размер. Немного полазил и написал это:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile
from os.path import join as joinpath

mypath = "путь"
for i in listdir(mypath):
    if isfile(joinpath(mypath,i)):
        print (i)
```

Проблема с выводом размера, даты создания.
Так же проблема в том, что все это должно быть в виде односвязного списка и храниться в динамичной памяти, помогите плиз с этим

Comment: старайтесь одной проблемой на вопрос ограничиваться, не нужно в вопросе всё задание целиком приводить. Если не знаете как получить размер файла в Питоне, то так и спросите (только об этом), не забыв упомянуть, какой именно размер вас интересует: размер на диске самих данных файла (без метадаты), размер если содержимое файла по сети послать (последовательность байт) [Найти суммарный размер всех регулярных файлов в каталоге, рекурсивно обходя все подкаталоги](https://goo.gl/i2TGfU)

Comment: Если не знаете как дату создания получить, то тоже отдельно спросите (упомянув, с какой файловой системой, операционной системой имеете дело) [Выбор последнего по дате файла из каталога](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477013/23044)

Answer (score -1):

вывод с указанными атрибутами можно вот так сделать

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from os.path import isfile
from os.path import join as joinpath
from os import *
from datetime import *

mypath = "/*path*/"
size = path.getsize(mypath)
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(path.getсtime(mypath)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
for i in listdir(mypath):
    if isfile(joinpath(mypath,i)):
        print (i, size, date)
```

Comment: почему вы думаете, что getatime имеет какое-то отношение к дате создания?

Comment: @jfs можете привести свой пример

Comment: см. мой комментарий под вопросом и соответствующие ссылки

Comment: @daedra это был не я, спасибо за код, очень помог я на + кликнул